# how to use carrierwave? Why I got "Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I'm using carrierwave to upload a file...but got some problem.

my form is like this:

```
<%= form_tag({:action => :submit}, :id=>"image_uploader", :multipart => true,  :remote => true) do %>
    <input style="file"...>
<% end %>
```

particularly, there is a file input. I want to upload user's avatar.

in avatar_upload.rb, I have written these two commands:

```
 process :resize_to_fit => [500, 500]
 version :thumb do
   process :resize_to_fill => [52, 52]
 end
```

in controller, I set these:

```
  avatar = params[:avatar]
  item.avatar = avatar
  item.save
```

it can save the file to the correct place, but does not resize nor generate a thumb version.

according to https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave

I think maybe I should use these:

```
uploader = AvatarUploader.new
uploader.store!(avatar)
```

I guess the "store!" method may run the resize process.

but, it seems to require <%= form_for @user %> because it needs an ID.

however, I just want to use form_tag, because I'm creating a new user, not modifying an existing one...

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

In your model just add

```
mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
```

you shouldn't need to do anything to the image from the controller.

You also need `@user = User.new` in your `new` action.

Comment: but the resize process doesn't work. I mean, the size of image is not changed to 500 * 500 and there is no thumb version file....

Comment: of course I got...i still do not know where the problem is...so I write a lib for my own..=.=